# SAPUI5, Two Calendars with own ids, without any sharement, setter will change the Month for both Calendars for no reason

Tags: sapui5

look the Code below

```
this.byId("FirstCalendar").getDateValue().getMonth()
3
this.byId("SecondCalendar").getDateValue().getMonth()
3
this.byId("SecondCalendar").getDateValue().setMonth(this.byId("FirstCalendar").getDateValue().getMonth()+3)
1627084800000
this.byId("SecondCalendar").getDateValue().getMonth()
6
this.byId("FirstCalendar").getDateValue().getMonth()
6
```

.setMonth, changes the month of both Calendars for no reason.

Why do you think that is the Case?

Comment: Please post the partial view definition where these contros are used as well

Answer (score -1):

Works as expected for me. You must have bound the properties to the same path, hence it is updating both. Provide the XML code please

```
XML: <DatePicker id="FirstDP" change="onCalendarChange"/>
                            <DatePicker id="SecondDP" change="onCalendarChange" />
                            <Button press="onDateTester" text="Date Tester" />
JS: onDateTester: function(evt){
        var cal1 = this.getView().byId("FirstDP");
        var cal2 = this.getView().byId("FirstDP");
        console.log("Cal 1 Month : " + cal1.getDateValue().getMonth());
        console.log("Cal 2 Month : " + cal2.getDateValue().getMonth());
        console.log("Month change");
        cal2.getDateValue().setMonth(cal1.getDateValue().getMonth()+3)
        console.log("Cal 1 Month : " + cal1.getDateValue().getMonth());
        console.log("Cal 2 Month : " + cal2.getDateValue().getMonth());
    }
```

result: 
Cal 1 Month : 2 
Cal 2 Month : 2 
Month change 
Cal 1 Month : 2 
Cal 2 Month : 5